# ClassNotFoundException in intellij even though class exisits in a dependency which have multiple versions?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We have a microservice project in which there are multiple modules.

There is a library let's call it as test2 which has around 4 versions in the whole project though I am using test2:2.5.0 in the module pom.xml.

test2:2.5.0 contains an interface TestConvertor which other libraries don't contain.
The package is com.bop.light2.TestConvertor.

A piece of code requires this class TestConvertor to compile, and compiler is able to find this class perfectly.

Though after running the code it throws ClassNotFoundException: com.bop.light2.TestConvertor?

Please let me know if there is any solutions to it. I am using intellij

Comment: Intellij has all the dependencies on one flat classpath but they may be in different scopes in actual pom files. There is also the transitive dependency rules. You'll need to post the relevant pom files for people to better understand the situation.

Comment: You can check the jar library where this class comes from via Navigate | Class action. Then make sure this jar is listed in [Dependencies tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html) of the module and has **compile** [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies.html#82fb3177).